# Javascript failing with syntax error on Webview on Android 9 and below but works on Android 10 and above

Tags: android, webview

I need to wrap up a website at work in a webview, and this must work on Android 8+.

The code is super trivial.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webContent)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        val url = getString(R.string.url_to_load)
        webView.loadUrl(url)
    }
}
```

When I run the code on Android 10 or above, the page loads just fine. But when I run it on Android 9 or below, it fails to render, and in the logs I see this INFO level log:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .", source: https://mysite/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-a67da37c3cc054e4.js (15)
```

This does not appear in the logs when the code is ran on Android 10 or above, indicating to me that the javascript on the site is using a version of Ecmascript that is not supported by WebVew implementation on Android 9 and below...

Could someone advise? Is there a way to workaround this without requesting that the websites JS is changed to be more back compatible?